# Eloquent select all children and sort them by order

Tags: sql, laravel, eloquent

I have problem write correct select with ordering for my Page table.

Actual implementation:

```
private function findPageBySlug($slug)
{
    $page = Page::with('children')
        ->where('active', 1)
        ->where('slug', $slug)
        ->first();
    if (property_exists($page, 'chidlren')) {
        return $page->whereHas('children', function ($child) {
            return $child->where('active', 1)->orderBy('order', 'asc');
        });
    } else {
        return $page;
    }
}
```

I need select all child of Page and order them by order column and also children can have another child and so on is no restriction to deepth.
Is posible to write select for this?

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to get all children and not filter pages by children, use `with()`. Instead of:

```
return $page->whereHas('children', function ($child) {
    return $child->where('active', 1)->orderBy('order', 'asc');
});
```

Do:

```
return $page->with(['children' => function ($child) {
    return $child->where('active', 1)->orderBy('order', 'asc');
}]);
```

If you want bith filter and load children, chain both `wherHas()` and `with()`